# What is the opposite of a multi-tribal society?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is the opposite of a multi-tribal society? (I don't mean a single tribe society; I mean modern forms of societies that are not based on tribes any more). a nation? a modern society? a national society? or ...?

‌

Comment: we need a sample sentence or two please.

Comment: "In the real-world, a multi-tribal society is more similar to a partitioned society compared to a modern society." Partitioned society is what I have defined.

Comment: @Shayan Please [edit] your post to include the context. Can you provide examples of the concepts you are attempting to contrast? A tribal society is almost by definition multi-tribal, but it's not clear whether you are talking about tribes in the sense of pre-modern organizing units of society or in the metaphorical sense where an occupation or political identity could represent a tribe.

Comment: The opposite of a multi-tribal society would be either a single tribe or a non-tribal society.

Comment: @choster edited.

Comment: How about *monoculture*?

Comment: @DJohnson Doesn't any of my own suggestions work?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact intended meaning, you might want to consider one of

> monolithic
>
> monocultural
>
> united
>
> uniform
>
> homogeneous
>
> non-tribal
>
> cohesive

Comment: Doesn't any of my own suggestions work?